# Laravel if id exist then update record

Tags: ajax, laravel

i want to set condition, if teacher already exist in database then update record, if id doesn't exist then add record in database. how can i achieve it using ajax in laravel?

**Update.js:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)  {
$('#update-data').on('click',function(){
alert("ok");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "teachers/" + $('#update-data').attr("value"),
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            data : $(this).serialize(),
            beforeSend: function() {

    },
            success: function (data) {
                    alert("ok");
            },
        });
    });
});
```

**Store.Js:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)  {

    $("#add-data").submit(function (e) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "teachers",
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            data:  $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Added");
                    data.responseJSON;
                    refreshTable();

            },
        });
    });
});
```

**Update Controller:**

```
public function update(TeacherRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $teacher = Teacher::find($id);
  if($teacher->save()){
                    return response()->json([
                        'status' => 'success',
                        'msg' => 'esecond has been updated'
                    ]);
                }
    }
```

**Store Controller:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
$teacher = new Teacher;
$teacher=teacher::create($request);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a custom method for this

```php
$teacher = Teacher::firstOrCreate($id, [
// Pass data here
]);
```

And if you want to check manually and traverse the request to another method

```php
public function update(TeacherRequest $request, $id)
{
  $teacher = Teacher::find($id);
  if (is_null($teacher)) { // If model not found, pass request to store method
     $this->store($request);
  }

  if($teacher->save()){
     return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success',
             'msg' => 'esecond has been updated'
      ]);
  }
}
```

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#other-creation-methods)

Hope this helps

Comment: should i add it in update controller?  what would be purpose of store controller then?

Comment: The store method creates a new resource from scratch, you can still call it

Comment: Updated my answer for that scenario

Comment: i added updated code, but getting, syntax error, unexpected ';' $this->store($request);

Comment: Don't just copy paste code from Stack Overflow, try to read and understand it, I forgot a ")" and added it now

Comment: it is still adding new record, not updating.

Comment: Thankyou,i think i am close, please review.

Comment: review what? You're not updating anything, you can call save() after you set properties of the model to something else

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent provides a `updateOrCreate` method so you can update or create a record.

```
$teacher = Teacher::updateOrCreate([
    // attributes to search for
    'name' => 'Test Teacher',
], [
    // values
    'grade' => 6,
]);
```

This would find a teacher with name 'Test Teacher' and update grade to 6 or create a new teacher with name 'Test Teacher' and grade set to 6.

> "You may also come across situations where you want to update an existing model or create a new model if none exists. Laravel provides an `updateOrCreate` method to do this in one step. Like the `firstOrCreate` method, `updateOrCreate` persists the model ..." - [Laravel 6.0 Docs - Eloquent - Other Creation Methods - updateOrCreate](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#other-creation-methods)

Comment: Thanks, it is still adding new record, not updating it.

Comment: then it isn't finding a record matching your search ... would have to see what you are passing for those 2 arrays